# does it Matter to store JWT token in Database?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jwt

First let me clear this, I use this technique because I read somewhere that it is best practice to do this. (IDKY)

I created an Login application or page. When user logs in the application, the server generate JWT token using user's email and id.
Basically I am using nodeJs's 'jsonwebtoken' library and it signs the data and generate token, like this -

`const token = jwt.sign({_id:id, email:email}, ENCRYPT_KEY);`

Now after token generation, server saves this token in Database and send the same token as response to client and client saves this token in Cookie.

Now when client do an API call, this same token is sent to server (with header) and server verify or unsign this token like this -
`const unsigned_data = jwt(token, ENCRYPT_KEY);`
this returns the same email and id field as JSON object and after this, server checks if the same email exists in database or not. If it exists then it returns true or whatever and if it doesn't then server rejects the client's API call.

Now my question is, what is the point of storing the token in the database at first place?
Or Am I missing some point here and making my application vulnerable??

Sorry for my poor English, I have tried very hard to explain the thing as clearly as possible.

Comment: It sounds like the way you are using it there is no point in storing it. One reason to do so could be if you want the server to be able to revoke tokens. It would then need to keep track of the tokens it has given out and keep a record if it's revoked or not.

Comment: @super Okayy thank you for your explanation. I do not really need to revoke the token because there only 1 to 2 users who can login. (Because it my personal Invoice management system).